# Use Bootstrap sticky footer template w/ fixed navbar in entire Durandal shell

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, durandal

I am wondering how to override styles of shell view being injected in Durandal inside div with `id="applicationHost"` ... I am trying to use common Bootstrap template ([sticky footer with fixed navbar](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer-navbar.html)) and it works as standalone but as soon as I use it within shell.html the "wrapper" looses its auto height...

Here is my `shell.html`

```
<div>
    <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- ko compose: {view: 'nav'} -->
            <!-- /ko--> 

        <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
            <!--ko compose: { 
                model: router.activeItem, //wiring the router
                afterCompose: router.afterCompose, //wiring the router
                transition:'entrance', //use the 'entrance' transition when switching views
                cacheViews:true //telling composition to keep views in the dom, and reuse them (only a good idea with singleton view models)
                }--><!--/ko-->                                 
        </div>
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
     <footer id="footer">
         <div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row-fluid">
                 <div class="span6"><p class="muted">&copy; ABC Company Inc. 2013. All rights reserved.</p></div>
                 <div class="span6 "><p class="muted pull-right">v0.0.1-debug</p></div>     
             </div>
         </div>
     </footer>

 </div>
```

the nav sub-view just has standard `<nav id="mainnav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">` and the styles are the same as on Bootstrap example page...

When I examine styles via Firebug I can clearly see that wrapper div has lost its full height...Driving me nuts! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the following style to my main html page after the styles necessary to get the sticky footer to work

```
/*durandal fixes*/
#applicationHost, #applicationHost > div
{
    height: 100%; 
}
```

The first selector takes care of the applicationHost div in the main html page and the second the one inserted by durandal (it has a class of durandal-wrapper, so you could make the selector more specific if you wanted). As you have an extra div in your shell.html file you may need the following:

```
/*durandal fixes*/
#applicationHost, #applicationHost > div, #applicationHost > div > div
{
    height: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: I tried this and several other variations, but there are issues with vertical scrollbar across different browsers and when using responsive layouts it breaks.